# URL redirection automation in UFT/Selenium

Tags: selenium, qtp

A URL of a webpage is being changed to a new URL.There are 200 such old URLs that have changed to new URLs.

**Test scenario** :1.200 old URls with their corresponding new URLs are present in two different columns in an Excel sheet.When an old URL is entered in the address bar,it will be directed to the new URL in the browser.

Can the above test be automated via Selenium or UFT for 200 URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more easily and much quicker by using Java `HttpURLConnection` class unless you are forced in a solution with Selenium\QTP

Open up the connection with the old link with the `openConnection()` method of `URL` class. Check for the response from `getResponseCode()` method. If response is not in 300 series then you have a problem. If response is in 300 series you have correct behaviour and check the redirected URL from the `Location` header.

Have a look at this link which will make things easier - https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the Exact same way in QTP. But i have a doubt.
i.e. If you have new URLs the nwhy u will enter old urls in  Browser addressBar ?

anyway u can look at the following
as u have said in Excel file old & new URL are mentioned Adjacent cells.

Then you might either use Following things to read excel file.

1) Create Excel.Application object 
 or
2) Use DataTabe to import Excel Sheet
 or
3) U can use Excel as ADODB connection

now just read the old URL from that Excel file & take value from the New url column cells & store it in a Varriable(let say : strNewURL).
Then you can do this & use FOR loop

set IE= CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application)

IE.Visible = True

'For loop here

' [intsomecount] is variabel which is teh no of times loops gonna iterate, in This case the Number of URL mentioned

For iterator=0 to intsomecount step 1

```
IE.Navigate strNewURL

wait 3
```

Next

lemme know if you concerns. :)